# How to check flutter web app performance using light house?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, lighthouse

The lighthouse shows the performance metrics for the flutter web app.. But is there any way to resolve those issues? because those issues are related to js,css, HTML files which are compiled from the dart.

So how can we resolve these issues in flutter web app??
please help

Comment: We can't really help you with this as you have provided no information about what problems you are facing etc. But in essence there is no massive difference between a flutter web app and anything else, if it says your Total Blocking Time (TBT) is high then you need to optimise your JS, if images are over sized then resize them etc. I would spend a little time understanding each report item (the bits under diagnostics and opportunities) and then ask more specific questions on items you aren't sure about.

Comment: But in flutter web, we are getting dart converted js file... So we don't have the option to edit these files right ??

Comment: So the only difference is that you have to edit your dart code rather than the JS. Dart gets compiled to JS, so if it says "remove unused JS" you would find the relevant JS that isn't being used for page load, locate the equivalent code in Dart and then do code splitting there. It is just an extra step, all the same principles apply.

Answer (score 0):

This website is specifically designed and covered to help those who are looking to improve the web performance.

Check out web.dev (https://web.dev/lighthouse-best-practices/) to learn more on web vitals, other resources, best practices and how to increase the web performance.

I hope this helps you to improve your flutter web app performance, if so reply back and share that how did you improved it.

**Edited:**
So, in this case you can share the light house report. Most of the time you can see what is the error message and just google it. You can get some ideas from that.

At the moment I gone through this website only, Even I'm also eager to know what made you to improve the report score and how? Once you found valid resources share it here too.

**Again Edited**
Hi I got this resource from stackoverflow email subscription. I hope you also got it. if not, check out this (https://calibreapp.com/blog/lighthouse-8)

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro... But this solution purely for web apps that are developed using js, HTML, and CSS... But in my case, js files are compiled from dart... So I don't have access to js files...So is there any other way bro ??

Comment: If I find it, I will definitely share... anyway thanks..